# I want to know about some app based on Phonegap+jqtouch on iphone or android

Tags: cordova, jqtouch

RT

Are there some beautiful app created based on Phonegap + jqtouch on iphone and android?
If you can give the names or links to download , that will be better.

Thank you~~

Answer (score 1):

The PhoneGap website has an [Apps Section](http://www.phonegap.com/apps) that showcases user apps. You may have to explore yourself, but each app profiled shows supported devices and also links back to the developers' sites.